# Python force a condition

Tags: python

Is there a way to force a condition to be true in Python? I've seen it being done in Haskell before and am wondering if you can do it Python. For example:

```
>>> 2+2==5
True
```

Comment: Write your own interpreter? ;-)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It seems inherently wrong.

Comment: [Write a program that makes 2 + 2 = 5](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28786) has an *interesting* Python solution. You *really don't want to do that* however.

Comment: -1: "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*" -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: "There are four lights!"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you just need to set four equal to five.

```
import ctypes

def deref(addr, typ):
    return ctypes.cast(addr, ctypes.POINTER(typ))

deref(id(4), ctypes.c_int)[6] = 5

2 + 2
#>>> 5

2 + 2 == 5
#>>> True
```

Obviously...

Comment: Here's a challenge to the daring among you: set 29 to something like 100 (because 29 isn't used much so it won't crash the interpreter) and try changing it *back*. Solution and other fancier attempts [available here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2441cv/can_you_change_the_value_of_1/).

Comment: Veedrac, rarely has anything on SO made me laugh out loud, but... LOL. (And I mean that in the best possible way!)

Comment: Hahaha, this is exactly the answer I wanted! :D

Answer (score 8):

You can redefine the equality operator for a subclassed int:

```
>>> class MyInt(int):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...         
>>> five = MyInt(5)
>>> five
5
>>> 2+2 == five
True
```

This is the least harmful of these answers to try out yourself. But if you do this (or any of these) in production code, you'll likely get fired.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.displayhook = lambda x : sys.__displayhook__(True if x is False else x)
>>> 2+2==5
True
>>>
```